# vite+vue3+vuetify - icons not displayef

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3, vite

I am using vite+vue3+vuetify alpha al latest version
no matter what I do, the icons not displayed on v-text-field
can someone point me to a good example.
NOTE THAT v-icon display the icon

BR

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the Vue 3 docs: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/ ... I was able to install by updating vuetify.js to reference the aliases... npm install of the icons did not work for me, I had to use cdn ref in index.html

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know what you have trying to do but if I understand you correctly so:
this is an example from the documantation:

```
 <v-text-field
        label="Prepend"
        prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker"
      ></v-text-field>
```

This is the direct link to what I belive you are searching for:
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/